# Create combobox with different items design using data trigger

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have defined the names and color in the backend using `C#` so I want to select the item cat and change it's other elements.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific what you actually want?

Comment: @ashtar I suggest to post more code

Comment: This question is not clear enough, please provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the XAML you are using to set up the ComboBox but best approach is to use a data template to set up the ComboBox items however you wish them to look. If you want the color box to not be shown if the Color brush is null, you could then add a trigger to the template to make it Hidden. Note that if you make it collapsed it will realign the layout of the other controls.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="cbDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle x:Name="clrBox" Fill="{Binding Color, TargetNullValue=Transparent}"
                   Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Width="16"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Color}" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter TargetName="clrBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

then to use this DataTemplate simply add it to the ComboBox like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource cbDataTemplate}" Width="150"/>
```

hope that's helpful...